# FTP download question

Tags: ubuntu, networking, embedded, ftp

An embedded device, running eCos OS, with FTP Lite Client. I want download file from device to local PC via FTP during terminal session.  FTP transfer initiates device, it ask to specify the FTP IP address, file name, user name and password. Once details entered, it starts FTP transfer. Device not allow connect FTP client from outside to initiate a file download request, it allow only transfer in one direction, from device to remote FTP host.

How to setup FTP application on Ubuntu for this purpose?

Comment: I advise clarifying what you want to do and using paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to setup FTP application on Ubuntu for this purpose?

You need an FTP *server* that will allow uploads.

I recommend `vsftpd`; here is a page that explains how to configure it for upload:

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39485